# C# & JS encryption methods return different results

Tags: javascript, c#, encryption, cryptojs

I have legacy encryption code in C# and now I have to do same encryption in JavaScript.
I've done some research and tried 3 different libraries, however couldn't get same results. Last library I used is CryptoJS and I must figure out why I'm getting different results.

Here are both code snippets:

C# code:

```
text = "chocolate";

    PasswordHash = "hashhash";
    SaltKey = "saltsaltsaltsa";
    VIKey = "iviviviviviviviv";

    byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);

    byte[] keyBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(PasswordHash, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SaltKey)).GetBytes(256 / 8);
    var symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged() { Mode = CipherMode.CBC, Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros };
    var encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(VIKey));

    byte[] cipherTextBytes;

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
      using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
      {
        cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
        cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        cryptoStream.Close();
      }
      memoryStream.Close();
    }
    var result = Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes);
```

**result ==> "8AbNsyyqHHfi/PEF/bbiew=="**

JavaScript code:

```
pass = 'chocolate';
//Creating the Vector Key
var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('iviviviviviviviv');
//Encoding the Password in from UTF8 to byte array
var passHash = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('hashhash');
//Encoding the Salt in from UTF8 to byte array
var Salt = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("saltsaltsaltsa");

//Creating the key in PBKDF2 format to be used during the encryption
var key128Bits1000Iterations = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(passHash, Salt, { keySize: 256 / 8, iterations: 1000 });

//Encrypting the string contained in cipherParams using the PBKDF2 key
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(pass), key128Bits1000Iterations, { mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, iv: iv, padding: CryptoJS.pad.ZeroPadding  });
var result = encrypted.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
```

**result = "dpgTA41PDyrM8ef9C1c8iA==“**

Comment: You seem to be using `Encoding.ASCII` in C# and `CryptoJS.enc.Utf8` in the JS..?

Comment: @stuartd - thought about it, same behaviour for both ASCII & UTF8 in given scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got a solution. Thanks to Luke Park who advised me that CryptoJS is using 4-byte (word) structure.

The issue which led to different results is that the key-size is (apparently) different. 
In C# 256/8 is actually 32 bytes length, however in CryptoJS, since using 4-bytes, 256/8 translates practically to 128 bytes length :(

Once I change the key size in the JS snippet to 256/32 ((256/32)*4 = 32) it worked perfectly and echo same results as the C# encryption method.

Thank you all
Nir

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your PBKDF2 salts.  CryptoJS uses a `WordArray` as the primitive to store salts.  That is, an array of 32-bit values.  Where as C# uses 8-bit values (obviously, it is a `byte` array).

Notice then that, in JS:

```
var Salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create([1, 2]);
```

Is, in C#, the same as:

```
byte[] Salt = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2 };
```

You can demonstrate this by outputting the following in JS:

```
var Salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create([1, 2]);
console.log(Salt.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64));
-> AAAAAQAAAAI=
```

CryptoJS doesn't like strings to be used as salts.  It doesn't like it at all.  You shouldn't be using a string or phrase as the salt anyway, it should be randomly generated and stored alongside the password hash.

Comment: That's exactly what "CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse" is doing: convert string to its word array representation

Comment: Yeah so the salt in C# vs JS is different.

Comment: You're wrong about it, the salts are the same. One is represented using bytes and the other using words, but the data is exactly the same. However - you gave me a direction which led me to a solution so thank you anyway :)

Comment: @Niro The data isn't exactly the same, as I have demonstrated above, but I'm glad you found your answer.